# Как вызвать исключение в двусвязном списке?

Tags: java, исключения, очередь

Что-то я вообще не понимаю, как вывести слово "exception"?

Код всей программы прилагаю ниже + тест с выводом который должен быть прилагаю ниже

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class QueueImpl implements Queue {
    private Node head;
    private Node tail;
    int current = 0;

    @Override
    public void enqueue(Object element) {
        Node a = new Node();
        a.element = element;

        if (tail == null) {
            head = a;
            tail = a;
        } else {
            tail.next = a;
            a.prev = tail;
            tail = a;
        }
        current++;
    }

    @Override
    public Object dequeue() {
        Node element = head;
        head = element.next;
        current--;
        return element.element;
    }

    @Override
    public Object top() {
        return head.element;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
        current = 0;
        head = null;
        tail = null;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return current;
    }

    class Node {
        Object element;
        Node next;
        Node prev;
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<Object> iterator() {
        return new IteratorImpl();
    }

    public class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {

        Node iteratorImpl = head;
        Node follow;
        boolean flag = false;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return iteratorImpl != null;
        }

        @Override
        public Object next() {
            follow = iteratorImpl;
            iteratorImpl = iteratorImpl.next;
            flag = true;
            return follow.element;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            Node prev = follow.prev;
            Node next = follow.next;

            if (prev != null)
                prev.next = follow.next;

            if (next != null)
                next.prev = follow.prev;

            if (follow == head)
                head = next;

            if (flag == false) {
                throw new IllegalStateException();
            }

            flag = false;
            current--;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        Node current = head;

        while (current != null) {
            if (current.next == null) {
                stringBuilder.append(current.element);
            } else {
                stringBuilder.append(current.element).append(" ");
            }
            current = current.next;
        }

        return "[" + stringBuilder.toString() + "]";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //test1();
        //test2();
        //test3();
        //test4();
        //test5();
        //test6();
        //test7();
        //test8();
        test9();
    }

    public static void test9() {

        Queue queue = new QueueImpl();
        queue.enqueue("A");
        queue.enqueue("B");
        queue.enqueue("C");

        Iterator it = queue.iterator();
        try {
            it.remove();
        } catch (IllegalStateException ex) {
            System.out.println("exception");
        }

        /* an output must be as the following:
        *************************************
        exception
        *************************************
        */
       }
  }
```

Comment: ну исходя из того что вы делаете it.remove(), то,  либо переполнение индекса, либо объект отсутствует какой-либо объект, или занят другим процессом.

Comment: Ваш код не запустится хотя бы потому, что вы реализовали не все методы интерфейса Queue - в их числе и метод remove(), который вы вызываете. Когда напишете remove(), Просто добавьте в начало if(current == 0) throw new NoSuchElementException();

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar всё равно не ловит исключение, как быть в данном случае?

Comment: Так, вам нужно кинуть исключение тогда, когда коллекция пуста. Попытайтесь вывести в консоль переменную current в remove - вы ее неправильно считаете. Обновите вопрос, добавив метод remove.

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar, спасибо Вам огромное и последний вопрос. Вообщем я установил поле flag внутри класса IteratorImpl и тест8 прошёл, но вот test9() вместо IllegalStateException выбрасывает, java.lang.NullPointerException. Как это исправить? Код я обновил

Comment: follow должен быть null, поэтому выбрасывает эту ошибку. При создании установите значение объекту follow

Comment: @MironsaysreinstateRedStar спасибо Вам огромное!!

Comment: @БогданКостевич и все же, я предложу свое решение. Посмотрите, может, что подчерпнете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как бы я переписал IteratorImpl:

```
public class IteratorImpl implements Iterator<Object> {
    Node now;
    boolean isFirstTime;

    {
        now = head;
        isFirstTime = true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return (now == null) ? false : (isFirstTime) ? true : now.next == null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object next() {
        if(isFirstTime) {
            isFirstTime = false;
            return now.element;
        }
        return (now = now.next).element;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        if(now != null) {
            QueueImpl.this.removeNode(now);
            current--;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
    }
}
```